# How can I stack rasters that have nearly exactly the same extent in R

Tags: r, gis, r-raster, extent, satellite-image

I am trying to stack multiband raster. They were created through the ESA Sentinel 1 Preprocessing tool SNAP. Every tif file hast to layer.

I loaded two rasterstacks and tried to stack them:

```
rs1 <- raster::stack("example/rs1.tif")
rs2 <- raster::stack("example/rs2.tif")
rsstack <- stack(rs1,rs2)
```

Then I got the following error message:

> Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent

The extent of the rasterstacks are nearly identical:

```
> rs1
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 2273, 2100, 4773300, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 8.983153e-05, 8.983153e-05  (x, y)
extent     : 8.183134, 8.37178, 48.49076, 48.69495  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20180110T053421_20180110T053446_020088_0223E7_69E7_10.1, S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20180110T053421_20180110T053446_020088_0223E7_69E7_10.2 
min values :                                                             1.729380e-07,                                                             1.077101e-06 
max values :                                                                 11.63158,                                                                109.76797 

> rs2
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 2273, 2100, 4773300, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 8.983153e-05, 8.983153e-05  (x, y)
extent     : 8.183171, 8.371817, 48.49071, 48.6949  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20180106T171534_20180106T171559_020037_02223E_CE2A_10.1, S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20180106T171534_20180106T171559_020037_02223E_CE2A_10.2 
min values :                                                             8.244981e-08,                                                             5.691331e-06 
max values :                                                                 6.012002,                                                                64.965996
```

What can I do to stack the two together? How can I adjust the extent to the other?

What I tried:
I also have an area of interest. SO I tried to crop both stacks to that area of interest an tried to stack them again:

```
shp <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand(example/area.shp)))
shp <- sp::spTransform(shp, CRS(proj4string(rs[[1]]))) 
rs1 <- raster::crop(rs1,shp)
rs2 <- raster::crop(rs2,shp)
rsstack <- stack(rsstack,r2)
```

> Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent

```
shp
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 16 
extent      : 8.183144, 8.371817, 48.49075, 48.69491  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 14
names       : fid,           Area,    BoundLen,         CentX,         CentY,       AreaIncI,  BoundNotIn,    CentXNotIn,    CentYNotIn,    PointInPol,    PointInPo1, CompactRat, CompactRa1, rast 
min values  :   1,     1440.64063,   168.67161, 3442255.57469, 5377418.66407,     1440.64063,   168.67161, 3442255.57469, 5377418.66407, 3442259.72286,  5377409.4208,    1.14669,    1.14669,    1 
max values  :  16, 76089100.06641, 89693.52095, 3451427.74745, 5393682.39749, 76858585.26953, 76662.07157, 3451427.74745, 5393682.39749, 3451416.96957, 5393687.75063,    2.57399,    2.90065,    1
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that your rasters are having the same coordinate system (crs : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs) only extent is different. First, you can crop it and then you can use `resample` function from `raster` package like

```
library(raster)

#Crop the raster
rs1 <- raster::crop(rs1,shp)
rs2 <- raster::crop(rs2,shp)

#Conversion of rasters into same extent
rs2_resampled <- resample(rs2, rs1, method='bilinear')

#Stack the rasters
rsstack <- stack(rs1,rs2_resampled)
```

Answer (score 1):

That can be achieved easily I guess. Let's try:

```
library(caret)

setwd("Your File Path")
# Open your reference Raster
Reference_Raster <- list.files(paste(getwd()), pattern = "Reference.tif$")
Reference_Raster <- raster(Reference_Raster)
# Open the other raster
Raster <- list.files(paste(getwd()), pattern = "Raster.tif$")
Raster <- raster(Raster)

# Now Let's Resample
Raster <- resample(Raster , Reference_Raster, method = "ngb")

# Let's Check the extent of both rasters, They are supposed to be the same.
extent(Raster)
extent(Reference_Raster)
```